# How to call parent function from instance of child?

Tags: php, doctrine

I have model

```
BaseUser.class.php
User.class.php
UserTable.class.php
```

**In user Class**
I have been override the delete function

```
class User extends BaseUser {
   function delete(){
    }
}
```

Now, if i want to call parent delete function .... how ?

**Example**

```
$user = new User();
$user->delete();  // will call the overridden delete
$user-> ??  ;     // want to call parent delete
```

Comment: Have you tried `$user->parent::delete();`?

Comment: yes, i tried it but it didn't work .... netbeans show it as wrong semantics

Comment: What about when you run the code in your browser?

Comment: Don't forget: your IDE is just a helpful tool. It's not the end-all and be-all of "valid code recognition." In other words, sometimes it gives false-positives.

Comment: Take a look at @j0k's answer. It covers pretty much everything you asked about.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Technically this is not possible from the "outside" (the public interface) for good reason.

If you have understood why (otherwise read below), and you actually know what you do, there is no reason to actually not offer the functionality:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
   ... 
   function parentDelete(){
       parent::delete();
   }
   ...
}

user = new User();
$user->delete();  // will call the overridden delete
$user->parentDelete();     // want to call parent delete
```

However if you ever do that, you should know that you have misused inheritance somehow. This must be an exceptional situation as I can not imagine any situation where you actually need that to do at all.

So try to formulate why you need that functionality so to give yourself better suggestions.

> Why is that bad?

For a very simple reason: In your software you do not need to know that `$user` has a parent or not. That is some detail you should not care at all about.

That will allow you to replace any user-object you have in your software with a childobject of user later on. This is important as you want to change your software over time.

If you make the internal detail part of the public interface you are robbing yourself the possibility to keep things flexible. Not being flexible is really a bad situation.

Comment: I do not agree with the "bad" statement.  Much like interfaces describe the signature of an objects methods, and when you `implement` that interface, when you `extend` a parent object, you should **should** very well know what that parent implements.  This is the crux of object extension.  There is no "bad" here.

EXCEPT: The idea that there is a need to call two separate methods.  Just have `User:delete()` call `parent::delete()` as part of it's method.

7 years old...  Why do I even bother... lol

Comment: Yes, the one that extends need to know, but the "user" of that type must not know any internal details (just the public interface). Most likely my English is not very precise, but what you comment is in the direction of what I wanted to say in that "bad" part, I perhaps should have provided the good example as well, calling parent::delete() inside the extending class's delete() method - err that is the answer, it's in there on top.

Comment: My own use case is this: I have a Mail() class, and now I want a DelayedMail() class to *fake* sending mail, but actually queue emails in a database. The faking is done by overriding the send() method. The easiest way to queue is to hibernate the instance and store its representation. No problems there! But later, in a cron job, I thaw those objects and now want to **really** send them -- and at that point I cannot use send(), because that would requeue them. I need to use the *parent's* send (I called it "actualSend()"). I don't see this as an abuse of OOP, rather the contrary.

Answer (score 7):

maybe try this

```
parent::delete();
```

Comment: i have object of user $user how to call on this object ?

Comment: your must call parent method in child method

Comment: @HUGO: You can't. From the outside both are the same. There are not two, but one object. That is what inheritance is for.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for the PHP [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) functions:

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
    echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
    echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
    parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
?>
```

If your class doesn't have a function called getMyFunction() calling `$b->getMyFuction()` will call the parent function. If it does, it will call the child function, unless the child function calls the prent function.

Comment: I think OP needs to know if `$b->parent::example();` will work.

Comment: @HUGO $b>example() will execute in the following: If there is no `example()` in the child class, parent will execute. If there is a function `example()` in the child, it will execute instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to extend `delete` if you need to call the parent one time?

Why not create a custom delete?

Like:

```
public function customDelete()
{
  parent::delete();

  // do extends delete here
}
```

Then you can delete an object using `->customDelete()` and you also can call the delete method from the parent since you didn't override the `delete()` method:

```
$user = new User();
$user->customDelete();  // will call the overridden delete
$user->delete(); // will call the parent (since you didn't override it)
```

And if you **really** need to override the `delete()` function, you still can create a kind of parent delete:

```
public function parentDelete()
{
  return parent::delete();
}
```

Then:

```
$user = new User();
$user->delete();  // will call the overridden delete
$user->parentDelete(); // will call the method that only call the parent
```

Comment: This is the best answer that gets at the key issue the original poster was trying to accomplish: expose both the customized and the not-customized functions of the inherited class, treating the child more like a wrapper (to be used by things that know how the parent interface works) rather than an opaque new class that would be used without knowing about the parent structure.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=149958) on codingforums. What it says (and I tend to agree with them) is that if you have an overridden function/method in a child class, an instance of that object will ALWAYS call the child method.

The `parent` keyword is akin to `$this` or `self` and can only be called from within the class itself.

If you want a child object to be able to call the parent method, just create another method

```
function parentExample() { 
    parent::example(); 
}
```

which only calls the parent method.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `call_user_func`. Yes, its bad practice, but its possible.

```
class BaseUser {
    public function delete()
    {
        echo 'BaseUser deleted';
    }
}

class User extends BaseUser{
    public function delete()
    {
        echo 'User deleted';
    }
}

$instance = new User();

call_user_func(array($instance, 'parent::delete'));
```

result:

```
BaseUser deleted
```