# PHP Chain with Parent Function

Tags: php, parent-child, php-7, chaining

I'm wanting to chain a method with the parent function of itself.

Example:

```
class Query
{
    protected $limit;

    /**
     * Returns some third object that isn't in this family.
     * This object represents the results, and also has
     * a first function that gets called in a chain.
     */
    public function get()
    {
        // Do Stuff

        return new /* ... */;
    }

    public function take($amount)
    {
        $this->limit = $amount;

        return $this;
    }
}

class ChildQuery extends Query
{
    protected $singular = false;

    public function get()
    {
        if($this->singular)
            return $this->take(1)->parent::get()->first();

        return parent::get()
    }

    public function singular()
    {
        $this->singular = true;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This obviously isn't the full set of functions, nor does it work, but you get the idea. I'd like `ChildQuery::get` to be able to call `Query::get` in a chain.

Right now, I have to do this:

```
public function get()
{
    $this->take(1);

    parent::get()->first();
}
```

Which is not appealing to me. Any ideas?

I'm running PHP 7, if it matters.

My end result would look something like this:

```
$query->singular()->get(); // ($query is a ChildQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just not possible to call a parent method by the public interface of an object (even if it is the same class/object like the current context). Please have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828729/2833639.

In my opinion your solution is the right way to go.

Off Topic: I recommend to read https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fluent-interfaces-are-evil/ to evaluate whether a fluid interface is good for your use case.

Comment: Also, I don't always use Fluent APIs, but there's times where they're super convenient, like Queries (even your related articles suggests this).